# Recording IP cameras on dual Synology Diskstations

Tags: ip, synology

I have currently a very elegant setup for surveillance, where 6 AXIS IP cameras are being recorded on a Synology DiskStation DS1513+.

I plan to install a further 2 IP cameras and what I need to do is this: Record all 8 cameras on the original DiskStation and at the same time have a second DiskStation (model indifferent) where I will record the feed ONLY from the newer 2 IP cameras.

If you have any experience with this kind of setup, I will appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So configure one Synology to record all 8 cameras and configure the other to only record 2. The last time I checked, these cameras were perfectly capable of sending streams to multiple clients simultaneously, so there should be no problem.